# GetResponse to Mailwizz via API

Tags: getresponse

Is it possible to do this:
- User enters his email in GetResponse form
- Form submits, email enters into GetResponse database
- The same email gets submitted to Mailwizz list

I think I can do this via GetResponse API where I have an intermediate file to do right?

Or is it possible to subscribe to GetResponse with just the email, like mylistID@getresponse? I know Aweber can do that and if GetResponse can do so it will be easier for me to code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could maybe look into using the Mailwizz php api, https://github.com/twisted1919/mailwizz-php-sdk

Comment: So it's the other direction? Mailwizz to GetResponse? I don't mind. :) Do you know if GetResponse allows subscription via email, something like Aweber? I tried looking for the answer but it doesn't seem so. Maybe it wasn't available in the first place.

Comment: GetResponse had "subscribe via email" functionality but they were going to deprecate it for some reason, as I know. You still could look at their callbacks — https://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/callbacks, maybe this could be the solution.